# How to join multiple colletion as one colletion with own shape of final document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections

**Users**

```
{
 "_id": "P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E",
  "login": "User-01",
  "name": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
}
```

**Moods**

which is time series collection

```
{
 "source": {
     "userId": "P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E",
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-06-11T12:44:13.333Z",
  "mood": "bad",
  "_id": "62a352b83859aaf975c6332d",
}
```

**contactRequest**

Also is time series collection

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-06-11T15:25:13.333Z",
  "source" : {
     "userId":"P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E"
   },
  "resolve": false,
  "_id": "62a351ff3859aaf975c63329"
}
```

I want to achieve the final document which will looks like this:

**Final**

```
{
 "_id": "P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E",
  "login": "User-01",
  "name": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "calendar": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2022-06-11T12:44:13.333Z"       //which is moods.timestamp,
        "mood": {
            "source": {
              "userId": "P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E",
             },
             "timestamp": "2022-06-11T12:44:13.333Z",
             "mood": "bad",
             "_id": "62a352b83859aaf975c6332d",
         },
         "contactRequest": [
             {
               "timestamp": "2022-06-11T15:25:13.333Z", //contactRequest is grouping by date with moods
               "source" : {
                 "userId":"P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E"
               },
               "resolve": true,
               "_id": "62a351ff3859aaf975c63329"
             },
             {
               "timestamp": "2022-06-11T18:23:13.333Z", 
               "source" : {
                 "userId":"P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E"
               },
               "resolve": false,
               "_id": "62a351ff3859aaf975c63329"
             },
         ]
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried aggregate it with **$lookup** parameter and it gave me two separate fields in User document, which is unsatisfying.
 I've also used **$project** parameter, but problem is with group results by date.
Does it possible to achieve that, aggregate multiply collection in final own shape document ? Was someone trying to do it in the past??

Here's a [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QBBdOwIrkr2) attempt that doesn't return everything correctly.

Comment: Mongoose has a `populate` function, you have to declare reference on the schemas

Comment: You could use `"$lookup"` within a `"$lookup"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Do u mean with using pipeline ??

Comment: Exactly!  You can do another `"$lookup"` in the `"pipeline"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs
 have u used to nested ```$lookup``` ?? Because I am struggleing with my pipeline. I need to aggregate in second lookup, datas from **contactRequest** collection to **moods** collection. I have to do it by **source.userId** in both collections and same **timestamps**, but only what I get is empty array of contactRequest.
There is how I am trying to achive that, can u check it, I'll be glad !!! 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/QBBdOwIrkr2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the question's mongoplayground as a starting point, I modified it a bit to return the document as requested.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // id comes from param
      "_id": "P4SpYVd1KjBaF4SKyVw0E"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "moods",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "source.userId",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "contactRequests",
            "localField": "source.userId",
            "foreignField": "source.userId",
            "let": {
              // truncate timestamp to start of day
              "moodsDate": { "$dateTrunc": { "date": "$timestamp", "unit": "day" } }
            },
            "pipeline": [
              {
                "$match": {
                  "$expr": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$moodsDate",
                      { // truncate timestamp to start of day
                        "$dateTrunc": { "date": "$timestamp", "unit": "day" }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "as": "contactRequests"
          }
        },
        {
          // don't return mood doc if no requests
          "$match": {
            "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$contactRequests" }, 0 ] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "calendar"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-pB_IzR6CgH).

Comment: Thank you so much ! Yes, this is what I was looking for. I try understand how the truncDate works. Well, if we trunc timestamp we decide compare each timestamp by day and then month and years are compare auto. Am I correct ??

And now If I want to group each result from aggregate like in the previous question. I can use $group parameter, but I have to decided which fields I want to fetch to results, with moods there is no problem but what about contactRequests if it nested in moods ??

Comment: I've tried do it this way but I am still struggling with $push contactRequest fields... Where do I mistake ? 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/hUpOmopQHwa

Comment: TBH, I don't know what is "the previous question".  I'm also not sure what you want to `"$group"`.  Perhaps it would be better if you ask a new question, showing examples documents and the desired output.